# How to pinch to zoom in image gallery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I want to have a multiple photos like standard gallery

[image: standard gallery]

And i want to pinch to zoom on **all** of photos. I probably have a UIImageView for every single image (am i right), so when I pinch in gallery view I want to zoom all gallery. Is this possible? How?

Comment: This is example from web. Doesn't matter. The problem is how to zoom entire gallery.

Comment: So when you pinch, you don't want one photo to expand, you want all of them to change size?  What are you using to get gallery cells like this, any kind of control?

Comment: This is "want to have" question. I have nothing yet, i'm looking for clue how to do it. And yes, I want to all of them change size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: put all your photos in one view, that would be subview of your scrollview. 
Then, in your scrollview delegate implement method

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

In which just return view that contains all photos. Do not forget to set appropriate scrollview content size and maximum and minimum zoom scale.

Answer (score -1):

put the pictures in a scollview. set the property `scrollview.scalePagesToFit;` . set the scrollView delegate.